# OnItemSelected not working on custom spinner adapter class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-xml

I can populate my spinner with the array list from API. But unable to select or populate the selected item from spinner and display to the user.

The onItemSelected method does not get the position of the selected item in the spinner.

**CustomSpinnerAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<String> userNames;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<String> userNames) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.userNames = userNames;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return userNames.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return userNames.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@NonNull
@SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"})
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, null);
    CustomTextView names = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_spinner_item);
    names.setText(userNames.get(i));
    return view;
   }
}
```

My logic in fragment.

```
private SpinnerAdapter customAdapter;
private List<String> eqIds = new ArrayList<>;

 apiInterface = ApiRequest.createService(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<EquipmentTypeModel> call = apiInterface.getEquipmentType("application/json", token, id);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<EquipmentTypeModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EquipmentTypeModel> call, Response<EquipmentTypeModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                eqIds.addAll(response.body().getData().getEquipmentList().getEquipIds());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EquipmentTypeModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    customAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(mContext, eqIds);
    spTypeModel.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    spTypeModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value from spinner you should you

```
String selectedValue = spTypeModel.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

or

```
String selectedValue = String.valueOf(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));
```

instead of

```
String selectedValue = String.valueOf(position);
```

**Update:** Change `getItem` method in your custom adapter to

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return userNames.get(i);
}
```

**Update 2:** I saw your problem, please change your code.

```
private SpinnerAdapter customAdapter;
```

to

```
private CustomSpinnerAdapter customAdapter;
```

then add this line after you add new data to your adapter.

```
eqIds.addAll(response.body().getData().getEquipmentList().getEquipIds());
customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add this line to notify your adapter about new data
```

**Update 3:** From your xml file, because your spinner height is 18dp.

- In spinner you set padding to 4dp (will be 8dp for top and bot)
- In custom text view you also set padding 4dp (will be 8dp for top and bot)
- So you only have equal or less than 2dp to display text content, it really small that why you can't see the content.

You can set your spinner height to `wrap_content` or keep current height but remove padding from spinner or from the custom text view. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for help @Son Truong but it's not working yet.

Comment: Can you add this code in `onItemSelected` method and let me know result when you click on an item. `Toast.makeText(mContext, eqIds.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Currently your listview does not display any data, does it?

Comment: No, the data from API is successfully added inside spinner items. I can also view the list inside spinner on its click. The problem here is the spinner onItemSelected is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180088/discussion-between-rakshit-sorathiya-and-son-truong).

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works (It will show you the value, not the position)

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: the onItemSeledcted is not working so no toast shows.